# Does conjugation preserve operator norm?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Suppose $X$ is a Banach space, $f:X\to X$ is a continuous linear transformation, and $h:X\to X$ is a topological isomorphism, i.e., there exist two positive numbers $M,N$, such that for any $x\in X$, we have $M\Vert x\Vert \leq\Vert h(x)\Vert \leq N\Vert x\Vert$, and the inverse of $h$ satisfies the same condition.

My question is, $\Vert hfh^{-1}\Vert=\Vert f\Vert$ or merely $\Vert hfh^{-1}\Vert \leq \Vert f\Vert$?

If $X$ is a Euclidean space, then do we have $\Vert hfh^{-1}\Vert=\Vert f\Vert$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe that if $\Vert hfh^{-1}\Vert \leq \Vert f\Vert$ holds, then applying this inequality to $\tilde f=hfh^{-1}$ and $\tilde h=h^{-1}$ we get the reverse inequality. So if the inequality were true, it would hold as equality.

But it fails. Let $X=\mathbb{R}^2$, 
$$
f=\begin{pmatrix} 0&-1\\ 1 &0 \end{pmatrix},\quad  h = \begin{pmatrix} 2&0\\ 0 &1 \end{pmatrix}, 
$$
Here, $f$ is rotation (norm 1), while $h$ deforms the unit disk into an ellipse. Problem is, if you deform, rotate, and deform in opposite way, you don't come back to the disk. 
$$
hfh^{-1} = \begin{pmatrix} 0& -2 \\ 1/2 & 0 \end{pmatrix}
$$